# A higher-dimensional "line of curvature"?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, terminology, curves-and-surfaces, curvature

Let $M$ be a submanifold of a Riemannian manifold $Q$, and let $\Gamma$ be a $d$-dimensional submanifold of $M$, i.e., $\Gamma^{d} \subset M \subset Q$.

Suppose that, for all (unit) *normal* vectors of $M$ along $\Gamma$, i.e., for all $(p, \eta) \in N(M) \lvert_{\Gamma}$, we have

$$ \tag{1} \label{eq1}
\nabla_{x} \eta \subset T_{p}(\Gamma) \quad \text{for all $x \in T_{p}(\Gamma)$},
$$

where $\eta$ is extended arbitrarily to a unit normal vector field in a neighborhood of $p$ in $M$. In other words, the covariant derivative of any $M$-normal vector field along $\Gamma$ remains tangent to $\Gamma$.

Clearly, if $\dim \Gamma =1$, then this condition simply says that $\Gamma$ is a line of curvature of $M$. And, when $M$ is a hypersurface of $Q$, it means that the shape operator of $M$ preserves $T(\Gamma)$..

**Questions.** Have the submanifolds satisfying \eqref{eq1} been studied already? Do they have a name?

Comment: Why should totally umbilical Gammas satisfy (1)?

Comment: @alesia Sorry I got confused. I'll edit.